# Getting a node.value from deep inside a TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a TreeView, containing folders and files, which are all stored in a database. I've now made a search function with an autocomplete search-function from the AjaxToolkit. Everything is ok, except that I'm struggling to find the node with the value I have from the search. I now that it has to be a recursive method, but I'm not sure how to do it.

So, the question is. How can i find the node in my treeview, based on the node-value that I already have. I also need to get all the parents node values. So I can select the node from this.

Here is some of the code (in the postback after the search is complete):

```
 else
            {   
                // postBack handler for AJAX AutoComplete Extender - JavaScript call: AutoCompletedClientItemSelected
                if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null &&
                Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "AutoCompleteExtender" &&
                Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null)
                {   
                    //i have the value for the node, but i need to search for it here, 
                    //and i also need the node-values from all the parents. I need the "path"
                    string nodeValue = Session["NodeValueFromSearchForm"].ToString();
                    string nodePath = "";

                    foreach (TreeNode node in TreeViewFolders.Nodes)
                    {
                        if (node.Value == nodeValue)
                        {
                            //I'm stuck here
                            nodePath += "\\s" + node.Value;

                        }
                    }

                    string prompt = String.Format("<script>{0}{1}{2}</script>", "javascript:__doPostBack('TreeViewFolders','s", nodePath, "')");                    
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "message", prompt, false);                    
                }
            }
```

In the `foreach` loop, I'm only getting the "root" folders (at the top). How can I do this recursively, to get to the childnodes, and finally, find the node that I have the unique node.value for?

**I got it working**
Thanks to Georges Oates Larsen's answer. I didn't think about just saving the valuepath of the node when users upload files in the treeview. So, now i'm saving the valuepath in my "files" table in the upload process and I'm passing that value in the `__doPostBack`

Comment: Finding the path, once you have the node, is easy: get the parent of the node, get it's parent, get it's parent, ... lather, rinse, repeat until there is no more parent. As for how you'd need to search for the node: it would help if you posted **relevant** code... Also; how would you be sure that node "A" somewhere in the tree is unique? What if a completely different 'path' also contained a node "A"?

Comment: Post C# code that relates to the TreeNode not the JavaScript / ScriptManager code...

Comment: @RobIII I added some more code. But I am sure that node "A" is unique, because the value that each node has, is from an auto-increment id field in my database.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I added more code to show where i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure how precisely your TreeView object works, or how you are storing its data (or if it even stores its own data). However, I do know a thing or two about tree searching algorithms.

The fastest way to find what you are looking for depends upon, primarily, if your tree is sorted. I am going to assume that it is not sorted, which means that solutions are going to have a worst case scenario of O(N), N being the number of nodes in your tree.

There are also different types of trees -- I am going to assume that you are using a normal old tree (Any number of children, no more than one parent, one root node). If you provide more information about the tree you are using, we can provide better information on how best to traverse it.

Given these assumptions, the pseudocode would be as follows:

```
public TreeNode[] SearchTree(Tree YourTree, SearchObject SearchingFor)
{
    return SearchNode(0, YourTree.RootNode, SearchingFor);//Depth is sent in so that our recursion can keep track of how many parents the node has. This allows us to use simple arrays which are far faster than any alternative serial data storage.
}

public TreeNode[] SearchNode(int depth, TreeNode YourNode, SearchObject SearchingFor)
{
    //Edge case


    if (SearchingFor.Matches(YourNode))//Does the node match our search?
    {
        return GetHeritage(depth, YourNode);//We get the heritage at the end because it's faster than using a dynamically allocated array for every single recursion we do when only one will ever get used. That practically makes the memory used exponential! Not ot mention all of the slowdown caused by the algorithms required for reallocation.
    }


    //Recurse

    TreeNode[] ret = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < YourNode.ChildNodes.Length; i++)
    {
        //Set the ret temporary variable to our recursion, then see if it is null or not
        if ((ret = SearchNode(depth+1, YourNode.ChildNodes[i])) != null)
        {
            break;//Exit the loop!
        }
    }


    //Return the result

    return ret;//If we find the correct answer, the loop will break with ret at the correct value.
    //If, however, we do not find anything correct within this node, we will simply return null.
}



//Final calculation for the correct result.

public TreeNode[] GetHeritage(int depth, TreeNode YourNode)//This will list every node starting from the node we found going all the way back to the root node. The first element in the array returned will be the root node.
{
    TreeNode[] ret = new TreeNode[depth+1];
    ret[depth] = YourNode;//Depth is actually one less than our length, so... Hurrah!
    for (int i = depth; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ret[depth-i] = ret[depth-(i-1)].Parent;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

EDIT: I have read a few of your comments:

A far faster approach would be to simply create an array and add reference to each node with the index of your "auto incremented ID" which points to the corresponding node every time you add something to your TreeView. Then to get the path to your number, simply look at the node at index[number] within your secondary array, and then follow its parents up to the root node! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I went for your last solution, saving the valuepath of the selected node in the upload process of files. I didn't think about that! Thanks!